# webpack bundles all the dependencies for different entrypoints in a single bundle and uses the same bundle in all the respective html's

Tags: vue.js, webpack-4

I'm working on a vue application which has 2 entrypoints. 1 of these entrypoints uses materilize-css and other does not. When i try to bundle these with webpack, it creates one bundle having materialize-css and uses that for both the entrypoints. This is increasing my bundle size for the 2nd entry point.

---Update---

if i remove the entrypoint having materialize-css, the bundle created by webpack does not have materialize-css. So, if any of the entrypoints uses materilize-css then it is bundled and used in all the entry points, if none of the entry points are using it, then it does not get included.

Comment: Are you using Vue CLI?

Comment: yes, using vue cli